# How should I go from Tile Coordinate to map coordinate?

Tags: javascript, mapping, openlayers-3

Is there a built in method for getting a lon, lat or x, y bounding box for an ol.VectorTile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the extent of a tile, you could use [ol.tilegrid.TileGrid#getTileCoordExtent](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html#getTileCoordExtent):

```
 var tileGrid = new ol.source.XYZ().getTileGrid();
 concole.log(tileGrid.getTileCoordExtent([0, 0, 0]));
```